# How can I set a timer for text?

Tags: c++, text, timer

I am making a command-line c++ application and I want text to be on a sort of timer because there is a lot of text. I already know how to make it so they have to press enter, but I want it to be automatic. What would be the simplest way to do this.

Example Output:

> Welcome to the Calculator Game! 
>   (1 second later) Do you want to play(Yes or No)?

Comment: What platform are you developing for?

Comment: This is hard to answer  -is this command line or GUI based? You could achieve what you ask for above with a simple sleep command but if it is GUI based you can use a timer event. Can you give more details?

Comment: @StackUnderflow Windows. I have added info about the base.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest thing is just to use `sleep(milliseconds)'.  Most operating systems have varous ways of doing timers as well.

Even better if you are using C++11, use something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello waiter" << std::endl;
    std::chrono::milliseconds dura( 2000 );
    std::this_thread::sleep_for( dura );
    std::cout << "Waited 2000 ms\n";
}
```

If you're not using C++11, then try the following:

```
#include <time.h>

void sleep(unsigned int mseconds)
{
    clock_t goal = mseconds + clock();
    while (goal > clock());
}
```

Docs here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_for

Comment: Thank you! I am not sure if I have C++11 so I am going to just use sleep();

Comment: If you are on windows, just `#include <windows.h>` and its a capitol `Sleep`. see here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686298%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: If you have C++11, then the code above should work.  What platform are you on? What compiler are you using?

Comment: I was using Visual C++ 2008, but I upgraded to C++ 11 and made my own sleep() function with the code you gave me. Thanks!